# Earliest reference on the calculation of derivatives by Fourier transform

Tags: ho.history-overview, fourier-analysis

I was looking for an earliest reference or the name of the mathematician who showed calculating the derivatives is possible in the Fourier domain?

The Fourier transform of the derivative is ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships))
$$
\mathcal{F}(f')(\xi)=2\pi i\xi\cdot\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi).
$$

Thank you.

Comment: Has to be fourier since he invented this to solve a differential eqn

Comment: To compute $f'$ this way, you have to first compute a Fourier transform and then compute an inverse Fourier transform, which is quite a bit of work to do. Ignoring historical firstness, what references do you have for computing derivatives this way?

Comment: Wojowu, I am a chemist by training. Our instruments generate data as time vs. signal. In that case, this is the only way to determine the derivative using FT method as far as I know and one can include smoothing before inverse FT. Is there a better way to calculate derivatives of the data $using$ FT methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Despite this being complicated by Fourier’s use of sine and cosine transforms, I think @PiyushGrover is right: Théorie analytique de la chaleur, [Art. 419](//archive.org/details/thorieanalytiq00four/page/557):

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \frac{d^{2i}}{dx^{2i}}fx
> =\pm&\int d\alpha f\alpha\int dp\,p^{2i}\cos.(px-p\alpha)\\
> \frac{d^{(2i+1)}}{dx^{2i+1}}fx
> =\mp\frac1{2\pi}&\int d\alpha f\alpha\int dp\,p^{2i+1}\sin.(px-p\alpha)
> \end{align}
> $$

and Art. 422 “Expression générale de la fluxion d’ordre $i$”.